# JQuery $.post not sending data to $_POST global

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The send() function is my JavaScript function which uses AJAX $.post. Though the function(data) is successful, everything I intend it to do is working fine. But the data being sent, in my example, recipient && chat_sent && date is not being sent to the global variable `$_POST`. The second part of the code is my PHP code. Though since the data is not being sent, the if statement IN MY PHP CODE cannot be executed. What could be the problem?

```
function send(){
var datetemp= new Date();
var tempUser = "<? echo $user ?>";
var tempRecipient = document.getElementById("recipient_chat").value;
var chat_message= document.getElementById("chat_area").value;

$.post("searchPresentation.php", {chat_sent: chat_message, date: datetemp,
    recipient:tempRecipient}, function( data ) { 
        $("#window").text(datetemp + $("#window").text() + tempUser + " - " + chat_message);
});
}
```

**This is searchPresentation.php:**

```
if (isset($_POST['chat_sent']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['recipient']))
{

//DO SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: done a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what was really received?

Comment: `console.log(data);` on success call..

Comment: it looks like `function(data)` is only happening if `isset($_POST['chat_sent']) && isset($_POST['date'])` is `true` so I do believe you are getting it in `$_POST`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!empty($_POST['chat_sent']) && !empty($_POST['date']) && !empty($_POST['recipient']))
{//DO SOMETHING}
```

all of param already set! "document.getElementById("chat_area").value" maybe is ' '  but it is set  so  use empty()